# vmware centos7 disk full?

Tags: centos, vmware, disk

I have already executed `reboot`, why is my disk still full?

OS: CentOS7 at vmware

**df -h**

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   37G   37G  250M 100% /
devtmpfs             902M     0  902M   0% /dev
tmpfs                912M     0  912M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                912M  8.7M  904M   1% /run
tmpfs                912M     0  912M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           1014M  138M  877M  14% /boot
.host:/              632G   39G  593G   7% /mnt/hgfs
tmpfs                183M     0  183M   0% /run/user/1000
```

**du -sh /***

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# du -sh /*
0       /bin
106M    /boot
1.3G    /data
0       /dev
33M     /etc
137M    /home
0       /lib
0       /lib64
28M     /log
0       /media
5.0K    /mnt
2.5G    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7661/task/7661/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7661/task/7661/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7661/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7661/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0       /proc
110M    /root
8.7M    /run
0       /sbin
0       /srv
0       /sys
1.1M    /tmp
6.8G    /usr
501M    /var
```

**df -i**

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# df -i
Filesystem          Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root 857440 344199 513241   41% /
devtmpfs            230728    397 230331    1% /dev
tmpfs               233411      1 233410    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               233411    524 232887    1% /run
tmpfs               233411     16 233395    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           524288    330 523958    1% /boot
.host:/                  0      0      0     - /mnt/hgfs
tmpfs               233411      1 233410    1% /run/user/1000
```

**fdisk -l**

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000bbe92

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    83886079    40893440   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/cl-root: 39.7 GB, 39720058880 bytes, 77578240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-swap: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**pvs**

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# pvs
  PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  cl lvm2 a--  39.00g 4.00m
```

**vgs**

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  cl   1   2   0 wz--n- 39.00g 4.00m
```

**lvs**

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# lvs
  LV   VG Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root cl -wi-ao---- 36.99g
  swap cl -wi-ao----  2.00g
```

**lsof | grep deleted** is empty

```
[root@localhost swoole_http_server]# lsof | grep deleted
empty
```

Comment: Any hidden files or directories under `/`? Test with `ls -l /.*`.

Comment: `find / -name '.?*' | xargs ls -lsh | awk '{print $6}'` Did not find hidden big files

Comment: Umount all filesystems you possibly can and do the `du -sh` again, please. If you copied data to `/mnt/hgfs` before mounting the filesystem over it, it will still take up space, but you can't really find out. (If you can't umount, you could try a rebind-mount of / to someplace else.)

Comment: "`/mng/hgfs`"  has been uninstalled, but the problem persists

Comment: what about the yum cache? had the same problem two weeks ago und with `yum clean all`and removing the mentioned directory after the "yum clean", it was all good again.